# why singleton methods (AKA: class methods) are inherited?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I'm a bit surprise about this behavior:

```
puts RUBY_VERSION # 2.4.1
class A
  class << A
    def my_method
      puts self
    end
  end
end

class B < A ; end

puts A.singleton_methods.inspect # [:my_method]
puts B.singleton_methods.inspect # [:my_method]
puts B.my_method # B
puts A.my_method # A
```

In metaprogramming Ruby 2 (amazing book BTW), Paolo Perrota says:

*Also, singleton classes have only a single
instance (that’s where their name comes from), and they can’t be inherited*

But we can see that the class method in the snipet has been inherited by B from A. So, can anyone explain me how that works?

Does this behavior means that classes are instances of singleton classes?

(I honestly wrote this before reding the part of the book which explain the mechanism of inheritance of class methods. But now that I understand it I still think is an interesting topic)

Answer (score 2):

Why class methods are inherited?

1. Each class has singleton class,
2. When there is an inheritance hierachy, the singleton classes inheritance chain mirror the one of
   the 'normal' clases.
3. In the Ruby method lookup process, the interpreter
   goes through the inheritance chain of the singleton classes.

```
puts RUBY_VERSION # 2.4.1
class A
  class << A
    def my_method
      puts self
    end
  end
end

class B < A ; end

puts A.singleton_class == B.singleton_class.superclass # true
puts A == B.superclass # true
```

So in the method lookup process the interpreter goes up to the singleton class of B, looks for the method `my_method` doesn't find it there, and goes up to the of the singleton class of A and there it finds the method and execute it.

But we should admit then, that having two inheritance chains of classes, they are in a sort in competition, in the sense that one of the two chains must be traversed first. But which one?, the one of the normal clases or the one of the singleton classes?

Well, if you know better please tell me, but code seems to talk:

```
puts RUBY_VERSION # 2.4.1

class Class
  def my_method
    puts "Those who seek for gold dig up much earth and find a little."
  end
end

A = Class.new do
  class << self
    def my_method
      puts self
    end
  end
end

class B < A ; end

Class.new.my_method # Those who seek for gold dig up much earth and find a little.
A.my_method # A
```

If the 'normal' chain of inheritance would have taken precedence over the chain of inheritance of the singleton classes, the result of `A.my_method` would have been the same of `Class.new.my_method` since the class of `A` is `Class`. We could see it more clearly if we remove the singleton method of `A`:

```
puts RUBY_VERSION # 2.4.1

class Class
  def my_method
    puts "Those who seek for gold dig up much earth and find a little."
  end
end

A = Class.new do
  # class << self
  #   def my_method
  #     puts self
  #   end
  # end
end

class B < A ; end

Class.new.my_method # Those who seek for gold dig up much earth and find a little.
A.my_method # Those who seek for gold dig up much earth and find a little.
```

Those this behavior means that classes are instances of singleton classes?

I would really like to have an answer to this question. But I'm not so sure about it. Would not that mean that for example `A` is both an instance of `Class` and it's own singleton class?  Double inheritance!?

If you know better, please share your knowledge. This is a very interesting topic :)

Comment: "Would not that mean that for example `A` is both an instance of `Class` and it's own singleton class? Double inheritance!?" – There is nothing special about classes here. *All* objects are both instances of their singleton class and their class. Also, this does not mean that there is multiple inheritance. For example, `[]` is an instance of no less than 6 classes: its singleton class, `Array`, the `Enumerable` include class, `Object`, the `Kernel` include class, and `BasicObject`, but that in no way means that there is multiple inheritance.

Comment: @JörgWMittag, I kind of see what you mean ( I guess), but I do not entirely agree with you. I do not  think that is correct to say that objects are intances of many classes at the same time. I think is more accurate to say an object has one class and many ancestors/ superclasses. `Enumerable` and `Kernel` are not clases, they are modules (Classes are kind of modules in a certain sense, but I think is both productive  and clear to name things by their own name)